# How to only select one multiple class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form that has checkmarks behind them. They all are tied to labels and have all the some class names. I could just make new classes or ID's for each one but figured their was an easier way to only select the checkmark that is inside that particular class?

http://jsfiddle.net/70fbLooL/

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".companyLabel").click(function(){
          $(".fa-check").toggle();
          $(this).toggleClass("companyLabelBackground");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have to find the element in relation to `this`.

Comment: you can use `.closest()` and `.find()` to dynamically detect closest div or element. for example ` $(this).closest('.companyLabel').find('.fa-check').toggle();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".fa-check").toggle();` will toggle all elements with class `.fa-check`.

Instead, use `find()` to get the closest element in relation to `this`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".companyLabel").click(function () {
        $(this).find(".fa-check").toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("companyLabelBackground");
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/70fbLooL/2/)**

Comment: Figured it would take someone two seconds to figure that out. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.closest()` and `.find()` to dynamically detect closest div or element. for example

`$(this).closest('.companyLabel').find('.fa-check').toggle();`

**code :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".companyLabel").click(function(){
                 $(this).closest('.companyLabel').find('.fa-check').toggle();
            });
        });
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/70fbLooL/3/)